# How to run CSS text animation in a sequence. (one line of text after another)

Tags: html, css

I have this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8uwu59sL/ Currently it's typing out every line at the same time, but I'd like to make it type them out one line after another with a second long delay in between lines.

This is the HTML:

```
<p>First Line...</p>
<p>Second Line...</p>
<p>Third Line...</p>
<p>Fourth Line...</p>
<p>Fifth Line...</p>
<p>Sixth Line...</p>
<br>
<p>Final/Blinking Line<span>|</span></p>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
body{
  background: #000;
  padding-top: 10px;
} 

p{
  color: lime; 
  font-family: "Courier";
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 30em;
  animation: type 4s steps(60, end); 
}

p:nth-child(2){
  animation: type2 8s steps(60, end);
}

p a{
  color: lime;
  text-decoration: none;
}

span{
  animation: blink 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes type{ 
  from { width: 0; } 
} 

@keyframes type2{
  0%{width: 0;}
  50%{width: 0;}
  100%{ width: 100; } 
} 

@keyframes blink{
  to{opacity: .0;}
}

::selection{
  background: black;
}
```

I was wondering, how do I do this? 
Also, is it possible to have the last line ("Final/Blinking Line") blinking slowly, and have the "|" blinking too, but at a different rate?
Thanks in advance for any help with this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*PURE CSS APPROACH:*

To achieve your first requirement, you need to use the css selector `:nth-child()`. How to use it: element:nth-child(n) where n represents the index of the child element in its parent.

For the other one you would need to separate your text and the "|"  each in a separate `<span>` to target them individually with a different animation duration (*speed*).

EDIT:

If you can use JQuery and you're planning on adding more lines over time, I would recommend using *DaniP's* answer, it's way more scalable, without worrying about adding a new css selector for every line. If you want to target a specific line to change something like animation-duration you could just target them individually adding an id and using css.

```css
body {
  background: #000;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
p {
  color: lime;
  font-family: "Courier";
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: type 4s steps(60, end) forwards;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
p:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
p:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
p:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
p:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}
p:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: 5s;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
p:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
p:nth-child(7) span:first-child {
  animation-duration: 0.8s;
}
span {
  animation: blink 1.8s infinite 8s;
}
p a {
  color: lime;
  text-decoration: none;
}
@keyframes type {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    width: 30em;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes blink {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
::selection {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<p>First Line...</p>
<p>Second Line...</p>
<p>Third Line...</p>
<p>Fourth Line...</p>
<p>Fifth Line...</p>
<p>Sixth Line...</p>
<p><span>Final/Blinking Line</span>  <span>|</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to manage the `animation-delay` value, one way is setting that for each one on CSS with `:nth-child` selector but if you can use Jquery, try this:

```js
$('p').each(function(i) {
  $(this).css({
    "animation-delay": i + "s"
  })
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
p {
  width: 0;
  color: lime;
  font-family: "Courier";
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: type 4s steps(60, end) forwards;
}
p a {
  color: lime;
  text-decoration: none;
}
span {
  animation: blink 1s infinite;
}
@keyframes type {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@keyframes blink {
  to {
    opacity: .0;
  }
}
::selection {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>First Line...</p>
<p>Second Line...</p>
<p>Third Line...</p>
<p>Fourth Line...</p>
<p>Fifth Line...</p>
<p>Sixth Line...</p>
<br>
<p>Final/Blinking Line<span>|</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

So I'll answer your original question first, as it's fairly straightforward with the above setup (which looks really cool, btw). Anyway, you'll want to add the following to each line in order to stagger their animations:

```
p:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}
p:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 84s;
  animation-delay: 8s;
}
```

Basically, just delay the number of seconds required for the line above to finish "typing". I'll look a little further into your question about the blinking rate!