# CSS Animate One Line at a Time

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

**UPDATE:** Still haven't been able to solve this problem, would love if anyone could help as I'm currently at wits end!

I have a class that is currently set to animate all at once but I'm trying to get it to go one line at a time, although the breaks in the paragraph will constantly be changing depending on the width of the window and the content if changed. Currently the paragraph class that is targeted is this:

```
<p class="animated">ANIMATE THIS TEXT ONE LINE AT A TIME</p>
```

But depending on the window width will render as this, or other possible variations depending on where the breaks decide to go:

```
ANIMATE THIS
TEXT ONE LINE
AT A TIME
```

I've seen some other examples like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37489282/5132072) which seperate the text into multiple paragraph tags to get them to animate one after the other but because I can't always predict where it will be breaking I haven't been able to find a solution.

This is what I'm working with at the moment:

```
.animated{
opacity:1;
-webkit-animation-name: flip;
-webkit-animation-duration: 0.15s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 3;
-webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes flip {
0%, 50%   {transform:rotateY(180deg);}
50.1%, 100%  {transform:rotateY(0deg);}
}
```

Hoping someone has the answer!

Thanks

Comment: What you could do is, set different classes with the property `animation-delay`, and use them in which line of the text you want to show

Comment: Not sure if jQuery can be used, if so, this might help http://jsfiddle.net/nathan/qkmse/

Comment: Well I haven't quite got it, but maybe this can help out. The only issue I'm having is with the first line, check out this fiddle I made and see if it works for you https://jsfiddle.net/e81anjfw/1/

Comment: @CumminUp07 wow that's really great! I tried to implement it into my Wordpress header.php (where the target is) but couldn't seem to get any result :/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but in case I did... I came out with the idea to animate the text letter by letter which would actually look like an animation of the whole text if it's correctly implemented. Here's the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0n5dnqau/4/

I expected the HTML to look similar to:

```
<p class="par hid">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, populo feugiat legimus vix eu, propriae  
    ...
</p>
```

Then we would run the script like:

```
var p = $('.par');
var animator = $('<span class="anim"></span>');
var hidden = $('<span class="hid"></span>')
var textLength = p.text().length;
var offset = 0;

function animate(letter_position) {
    var text = p.text();
    p.text('');
    var textBefore = text.substring(0, letter_position - 1);
    var textAfter = text.substring(letter_position, textLength);
    var letter = text.substr(letter_position - 1, 1);
    animator.text(letter);
    hidden.text(textAfter);
    p.append(textBefore);
    p.append(animator);
    p.append(hidden);
}

var interval = setInterval(function(){
    if (p.hasClass('hid')) p.removeClass('hid');
    if (offset - 2 === textLength) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        p.children('.anim').remove();
        p.children('.hid').remove();
        return;
    } 
    animate(offset);
    offset++;
}, 100);
```

And the CSS for that is really simple:

```
.anim {
    animation: show .01s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes show {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.hid {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

What it does is it actually splits the text to 3 parts. `beforeText` is added to the paragraph without any styles, it's just the plain paragraph's text. Then `animator` is the letter that's going to be animated and the `hidden` part is going to be hidden (not surprising I guess). Then we append the paragraph with those 3 parts in that exact order.

You can play around with the animation effects and length and the interval from setInterval to make it more likely the animation you want to achieve.