# How to sequence multiple text animations one after one?

Tags: html, css

using CSS and html how can we sequence multiple text animations one after one?

I am not able to print multiple text animations in a sequence in html and CSS...

Comment: There are several ways. One way is to use the `animation-delay` property in CSS, Another way to use JavaScript to start the animations one after the other. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37489058/how-to-run-css-text-animation-in-a-sequence-one-line-of-text-after-another

Comment: Please could you put some code into your question which shows some at least of the animations you are talking about. There may be a way of combining them into one animation for example.